# How do you access variables that are allocated on the heap in C++ even after leaving the scope?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator, scopes

I'm having issues understanding the new keyword in C++. I understand that in order to not have memory popped off from stack after leaving scope; you can store it on heap. However in this example I get an error saying "identifier p is undefined"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person {
public: 
    int age; 
    std::string name;

    Person() {

    }

    Person(int a, std::string n): age(a), name(n){}
};


int main() {
    {
        Person* p = new Person(5, "bob");
    }

    std::cout << (*p).age; 

}
```

As you can see in my main function I've created another scope where I create a Person object on heap, from what I know the object will still exist after leaving the curly brackets, but then why is it not recognizing object p?

I've tried derefrencing p but the error remains the same. 
Any help would be great! 
Thanks

Comment: If you use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique()` you won't have a leak. `new` is a code smell in C++.

Comment: Side note: I'd rather see `p->age` than `(*p).age`.

Comment: It is what you call a 'memory' leak. At the time the last pointer to an object on the heap goes out of scope, there's no (legal) way to get that object back, it's lost in space (and thus the resources it was built with, i. e. the memory)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the object still exists since you never deleted it.  That is only half the issue though.  The name `p` is local to the nested scope you declared it in.  Once you exit that scope, `p` is destroyed and you can no longer access the object that you created.

What you would need would be

```
int main() 
{
    Person* p;
    {
        p = new Person(5, "bob");
    }

    std::cout << (*p).age; 
}
```

and now you can access `p` since it was declared in `main`'s scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! this was so simple I can't believe I didn't think about it like you explained

Answer (score 0):

`Person* p` is a `Pointer*` type object with automatic storage (a "local variable"). That pointer, like any object with automatic storage, only exists until the end of the scope it was declared in. Once you reach the closing `}` of the block scope you made, there is no such thing as `p` anymore, that pointer has stopped existing.

While `p` doesn't exist, what it used to point to still does. Your `Person` is leaked and gone. Without a pointer or reference to it, there's no way to get it back and no way to clean it up. Make sure to keep `p` or another pointer to it until you `delete` it.

Moving the declaration of `Person* p` to outside of the scope (or removing the artificial scope entirely) will solve this problem. In that case, `p`'s lifetime is linked to `main`'s scope and will still exist by the time you try to `std::cout` it's `age` member.

Consider using smart pointers to at least avoid leaks like this. `std::unique_ptr<Person> p` would automatically `delete` the `Person` when the last (and only) pointer ceases existing.

Answer (score 0):

The object is still there, and if you do not delete it you have a memory leak. If you want to access it elsewhere you need to keep a reference to it (reference in the general sense, ie pointer or reference).

The variable however, is only accesible in the scope where it is declared. You could for example fix it by doing:

```
int main() {
    Person* p;
    {
        p = new Person(5, "bob");
    }
    std::cout << (*p).age; 
    delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you create a variable between curly braces it will have a block scope.

And it will die after the block ends(the pointer p itself which is 32/64 bit value depending on your machine). and the memory allocated by new is still in
the heap but the pointer itself isn't.(which will cause a memory leak).

I don't know what do you want to do exactly but you can do

```
int main() {
Person * ptr;
    {
        Person* p = new Person(5, "bob");
        ptr = p;
    }

    std::cout << (*ptr).age;

    //free the memory if you will not use it anymore
    delete ptr;
}
```

Then you can use ptr to point to the block create by new.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person* p
```

the pointer is used to store the memory address of the object, memory has been assigned on the heap to store the member variables, you have to explicitly use delete which calls the default destructor to destroy that object, since p is used in the block, you cannot call it from outside.